# Composite Pattern in Java : Practical Implementation

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I was reading the book "Design Patterns" and going over Composite Pattern. Please go through this [link](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~aaguiar/as/gof/hires/pat4cfso.htm) to get the context of the problem. The following class diagram is given in the book :-
[image]

My question is about the practice of implementing this pattern in Java.

1. How will `Graphic` be defined -- as an **Interface** or an **abstract class**?
2. `Graphic` declares method like `Add(Graphic)`, `Remove(Graphic)` and `GetChild(int)`. The classes that are implementing (or extending) `Graphic` will have to give their implementation to these methods. But classes like `Line`, `Rectangle` and `Text` do not need these methods. So while implementing `Graphic` interface or extending `Graphic` abstract class, what will these classes do with respect to these methods. Can they have blank or empty implementations for these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take is this:

1. Since `Graphic` is the primary (or only) class the clients interact with - it should be an interface. While it isn't "wrong" for it to be an abstract class, it is both better design and also interfaces are better suited to be passed between server and client in patterns such as proxy.
2. Your point here raises the necessity to differentiate between a `SimpleGraphic` which is not composed of child graphics and `ComplexGraphic` which is.  These abstract classes implement the interface and contain default implementation for some of the interface's methods. (I would make `SimpleGraphic` throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` for all tree related methods)  All concrete Graphics would extend one of the above mentioned abstract classes. I would also add `canAddGraphic()` method to the interface to ease the construction of complex graphics by clients.

Answer (score 2):

> 1.How will Graphic be defined -- as an Interface or an abstract class?

Conceptually, `Graphic` should be an interface.
Now, it makes no sense to duplicate the implementation of common methods for leaf components.
So, adding a `AbstractLeafGraphic` abstract class that implements `Graphic` may make sense.

> 2. ... So while implementing Graphic interface or extending Graphic abstract class, what will these classes do with respect to these
>      methods. Can they have blank or empty implementations for these
>      methods?

Composite pattern is a pattern providing a simple API to manipulate in a transparent way composite (that contains components) and leaf components.
It has advantage : API easiness. 
It has drawbacks : defining methods for classes that don't need really them.

From the book you are quoting, a simple and fine advise is given :

> Usually it's better to make Add and Remove fail by default (perhaps by
>   raising an exception) if the component isn't allowed to have
>   children...

Answer (score 2):

[Composite Design Pattern Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCxj1.png)

Please refer to the image from the above link for composite design pattern.

A composite Pattern basically delegates the responsibility to the children. There are three elements of interest in a composite pattern.

**1. Core Interface** This interface is the root of the pattern. In our example, it's Drawing interface. It contains only the behavior that needs to be delegated. It doesn't contain behaviors related to the creation of the composite.

**2. Composite Interface** This is the extension of *Core Interface* It defines *Add* method to add one object in another thus making **composite design**.

Both these interfaces can be implemented by a number of subclasses.

Objects implementing the *core* interface is termed as **terminal elements**.
E.g. Line, Rectangle

Objects implementing the *composite interface* is termed as **composite element**
E.g. Layer, Drawing

A composite may contain another composite or terminal. Thus it provides a tree structure. Any operation performed on the root is delegated to the children.

Creation of composite object is outside the scope of composite pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

Based on the UML diagram you supplied, I'd say that Graphic is an Abstract class, due to the *italicized* name. (Check out [UML, Abstract Classes and Methods, and Interfaces](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/35) for more information.) However, as others have suggested, you could use an interface as well. This will give you more modularity in the future.

**2.**

The use for this pattern is ".. Composite pattern is an ***abstract* class** that represents both primitives and their containers." as the [source for your picture describes](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~aaguiar/as/gof/hires/pat4cfso.htm) in the first paragraph after the first UML diagram.

A better description for this pattern can be found on [Sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite), where you'll find good examples and a bit more information regarding the uses for this pattern.

`Line`, `Rectangle` and `Text` are all simple "leaf"-components, which do not contain any children as `Graphics`, and therefore don't need these methods.

> So while implementing Graphic interface or extending Graphic abstract class, what will these classes do with respect to these methods. Can they have blank or empty implementations for these methods?

I'd say that this diagram is a bit confusing, as you wouldn't want to have empty methods dangling in your code. You could implement these methods to throw exceptions or handle different type of conversions. For example: Adding another `Graphic`object to a `Text`object could be implemented to create a `Composite` object of both `Graphics` as leaves. This can be somewhat complicated, though.

However, what I learned when working with this pattern is that your goal is to give a user the ability to work with both compositions and single objects uniformly. You can adapt the implementation to accomplish this goal however you want. That's the thing with patterns, they're guidelines for structure and behaviour, not code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're reading a book that considers implementation in C++ so the class diagram reflects the lack of interfaces (in the Java sense). So if you plan to implement in C++ your answer is abstract class.

For an interface based approach consider the Wikipedia article where interface based examples are given. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

As for the second question - it is a trade-off. You can either make it do nothing, risking the user of your library doing meaningless operations like adding children to leaf nodes. Or you can type-check each class before using it and act accordingly.